# Swift 3: Unrecognised selector sent to instance (KeyboardWillShow)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, notificationcenter

I search a lot about it on stack overflow but according to their solution my program is same as mention but still not working.

```
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:Selector(("keyboardWillShow:")), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}


func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification: notification)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument for selector should be `#selector(keyboardWillShow)`, like so:

```
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification: notification)
}
```

Comment: i wrote it as u mention but is still giving an  error and showing warning on Selector argument that no method declared with objective-c "keyboardWillShow"

Comment: I've updated my answer. The new syntax for Swift is: `#selector(keyboardWillShow)`

Comment: Thanks buddy @Michael Patzer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use #selector then it will give uncaught exception of NSType and hence it will terminate the app.